# "Missing Credentials" error on my login page using passportjs (Two strategies)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am using two strategies, one for admin login and the other for student login, Admin login is working fine but Student Login is showing "Missing credentials" error even when I enter the right username/password.

My full code is [HERE](https://www.github.com/shuhulkaul/scientia)

I have double checked the field names in "studenttemp" collection.
I am using handlebars for frontend.

**/views/studentlogin.handlebars**

```
    <h2 class="page-header"> Student Login </h2>
    <form action="/users/studentlogin" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"> <br>
    <input type="password" name="spassword" id="spassword" placeholder="Student Password"> <br> <br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
     </form>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

//database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/scientia', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.')
    , root    = namespace.shift()
    , formParam = root;

  while(namespace.length) {
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
      }
      return {
        param : formParam,
        msg   : msg,
        value : value
      };
    }
  }));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next()
 });




app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

**/routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//models
var Admin = require('../models/admin');
var Student = require('../models/student');
// Registered
router.get('/admindashboard', function (req, res) {
    res.render('admindashboard');
});
router.get('/studentdashboard', function (req, res) {
    res.render('studentdashboard');
});

router.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});
// Login

router.get('/admin/login',  function(req, res){
    res.render('adminlogin');
});

router.get('/student/login',  function(req, res){
    res.render('studentlogin');
});


//Registration Form

router.get('/studentregister', function (req, res) {
    res.render('studentregister');
});

router.get('/facultyregister', function (req, res) {
    res.render('facultyregister');
});


// Register Student
router.post('/studentregister', function (req, res) {
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lname;
    var dname = req.body.dname;
    var mname = req.body.mname;
    var coerid = req.body.coerid;
    var phone = req.body.phone;
    var address = req.body.address;
    var pincode = req.body.pincode;
    var state = req.body.state;
    var lateral = req.body.lateral;
    var yoj = req.body.yoj;
    var branch = req.body.branch;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('fname', 'First Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lname', 'Last Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('dname', "Father's Name is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('mname', "Mother's Name is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('coerid', 'COER ID is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('phone', 'Mobile Number is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('address', 'Address is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('pincode', 'Pincode is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('state', 'State is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lateral', 'Are you a lateral Entry student?').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('yoj', 'Year of Joining is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('branch', 'Branch/Course is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not         match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    res.render('studentregister', {
        errors: errors
    });
}
else {
    //checking for email and username are already taken
    Student.findOne({ phone: phone 
    }, function (err, mobile) {             
    Student.findOne({ coerid: coerid 
        }, function (err, id) {
                Student.findOne({ email: { 
                    "$regex": "^" + email + "\\b", "$options": "i"
            }}, function (err, mail) {
                    if (id || mail || mobile) {
                        res.render('studentregister', {
                            id: id,
                            mail: mail,
                            mobile : mobile
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        var newUser = new Student({

                            fname : fname,
                            lname : lname,
                            dname : dname,
                            mname : mname,
                            coerid : coerid,
                            phone : phone,
                            address : address,
                            pincode : pincode,
                            state : state,
                            lateral : lateral,
                            yoj :yoj,
                            branch : branch,
                            email : email,
                            password : password

                        });
                        Student.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            //console.log(user);
                        });
                req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now     login');
                        res.redirect('/users/student/login');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
}
});


passport.use('admin-local', new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
    Admin.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
        }

        Admin.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err,     isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
Admin.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});




//Check Student Login Credentials

passport.use('student-local', new LocalStrategy(
function (email, password, done) {

    Student.getUserByUsername(email, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
        }

        Student.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
Student.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});


//post

router.post('/adminlogin',
passport.authenticate('admin-local', { successRedirect:     '/users/admindashboard', failureRedirect: '/users/admin/login', failureFlash:     true }),
function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/studentlogin',
passport.authenticate('student-local', { successRedirect:     '/users/studentdashboard', failureRedirect: '/users/student/login',     failureFlash: true }),
function (req, res) {

    res.redirect('/');
});


//logout

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
req.logout();

req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

res.redirect('/users/home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/student.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

  },
  lname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

  },
  dname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

  },
  mname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

  },
  coerid: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique:true,
    trim:true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique:true,
    trim:true

  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

  },
  pincode: {
    type: Number,
required: true,
trim:true
  },
  state: {
type: String,
required: true,

  },
  lateral: {
type: String,
required: true,

  },
  yoj: {
type: Number,
required: true,

  },
  branch: {
type: String,
required: true,

  },
  email: {
type: String,
required: true,
trim:true,
unique:true
  },
  password: {
type: String,
    required: true,
  }



});

var Student = module.exports = mongoose.model('studenttemp', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    });
});
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
Student.findOne(query, callback);

}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
Student.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **/views/studentlogin.handlebars** file, I have to **strictly** put the name and id of the two input fields to "username" and "password" instead of "email" and "spassword".